# Is there a locate type command for finding hostnames?

Tags: networking, command-line, server, hostname, locate

I work on a large network with thousands of instruments, and sometimes, I wish I could just use a command like `$locate --hostname dawar` to locate information about the IP, and full hostname of the computer(s) named "dawar" on the network. I wrote a little program that uses the depreciated C function gethostsbyname and gethostsbyaddress, and I guess I could write in a search function. But I'm curious if there is a similar program that can search the nameserver,... that I do not have to write.

Alternatively, what is a non-depreciated function for the equivalent gethostbyname in C?

Here is output of nslookup, which I don't want to use, given how the output appears;

```
nslookup 123.111.129.108
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

108.129.111.123.in-addr.arpa    name = RM135.domain.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's so problematic about that output. `108.129.111.123.in-addr.arpa` is how it does reverse lookup, and the hostname is reported in `name = `. Here's, for example, my equivalent output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23388488/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the "dig" utility

```
> # dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8753
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             120     IN      A       209.85.202.100
google.com.             120     IN      A       209.85.202.139
google.com.             120     IN      A       209.85.202.102
google.com.             120     IN      A       209.85.202.101
google.com.             120     IN      A       209.85.202.113
google.com.             120     IN      A       209.85.202.138

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.228#53(192.168.0.228)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct 27 14:43:06 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 124
```

Comment: I'd have to provide complete hostname?  is there a way to search partial hostname, in the domain?  there are hundreds of sub-domains here, which is why i have a tough time recalling the full host-names.. right now, I would just ask the nameserver for every hostname in the subdmain, and grep out the one I want, its pretty inefficient, but the console cisco provides doesn't even have a search function, its all check-boxes, and lists.

Comment: As far as I am aware, you would have to provide the full domain name. You could also do a nmap -sP 192.168.1.* and

Comment: @user98651: And what?

Comment: Oops. ...and grep for the appropriate hostname. eg.  nmap -sP '192.168.1.*' | grep myhost

Answer (score 1):

`nslookup dawar` or `getent hosts dawar` might serve your purpose, depending on the specific use case. Both assume that the FQDN can be obtained from search domains specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`. `nslookup` can also do reverse lookups, but I'm not sure about `getent`. There's also the more powerful `dig` command, and iirc, a `hosts` command.

Comment: nslookup writes the IP backwards, (which is obnoxious and an extra step to get the IP)

Comment: @j0h backwards?

Comment: It definitely does not print the IP backwards.

Comment: sure does, at least on this network. Im not in charge of the name-server here, Im not sure why it does that. I just looked at nslookup google.com and I see what you guys mean.

Comment: Can you post example output of what you mean? @j0h